# Underscore JS source – How is this saving bytes?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, minify

While reading through the [commented underscore source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html), I encountered this line at the beginning:

> Save bytes in the minified (but not gzipped) version:

```
  var ArrayProto = Array.prototype, ObjProto = Object.prototype, FuncProto = Function.prototype;
```

What exactly is done here – saving bytes by avoiding line breaks?

To me this seems rather obscure, especially because it's the only occurrence of that technique, which makes me believe there might be more to it.

Comment: to explain his specific language in the comment: gzip would replace the whole long repetitive parts, whereas just a min would repeat them, so he shortens the long repeats down to smaller repeats. `ArrayProto` is shorter than `Array.prototype`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var ArrayProto = Array.prototype, ObjProto = Object.prototype, FuncProto = Function.prototype;
```

is [equivalent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to

```
var ArrayProto = Array.prototype;
var ObjProto = Object.prototype;
var FuncProto = Function.prototype;
```

The saved bytes aren't related to missing line breaks, as the minifier would remove them if they were present in the code.

By declaring a variable to replace `Array.prototype`, and assuming the minifier will replace the variable name with a one letter variable name (which is probable), you gain 14 characters per following occurrence of `Array.prototype` that you replace with `ArrayProto`. The minifier can't of course change `Array.prototype` as it wouldn't be found with a different name.

As noted, the gain is dubious and hard to measure for a gzipped code as the compression is more efficient on texts with repetitions.

This is a micro optimization. When you do use a lot an expression which can be renamed, you can try assigning it to a variable and reuse that variable but only if you measure the gain **and** if having a file a few bytes lighter matters (which is rare) **and** if you're confident you don't hinder readability and maintainability (note, though, that readability can also be improved by having a name to replace an expression).

You find the same optimization under disguise in the more common pattern:

```
(function(window, undefined){
   // window and undefined are replaced by one letter
   // names by the minifier
})(window, undefined);
```